# PHP - Dealing with dashes in RSS

Tags: php, xml, syntax, rss, escaping

I'm fairly new to PHP, but I'm trying to parse parts of an RSS feed to render over to HTML. The issue is that just about every tag in the feed has a dash in it and that's making it hard to deal with. I tried doing something like $home->{'pub-code'}->{'ad-type'} etc. but that didn't seem to work either. What I have so far is the following:

```
    foreach ( $topRSS->channel->item as $home ) 
         {$returnValue .= "<li><span class=\"Title\">".$home->pub-code->ad-type->account-name."</span><br><a class=\"Link\" href=\"#\">".$home->pub-code->ad-type->ad-content."</a></li>";
         $counter++;
         if ($counter > 4)
             break;
         }
```

which is an attempt at iterating over an RSS feed with items that look like :

```
 <item>
  <pub-code>
    <ad-type>
      <cat-code>Jobs</cat-code>
      <class-code/>
      <ad-number>12345</ad-number>
      <ad-number>12345</ad-number>
      <start-date>03/14/2018</start-date>
      <image><image/>
      <account-number>12345</account-number>
      <account-name>GENE BROWN</account-name>
      <addr-1>12533 WALSINGHAM RD</addr-1>
      <addr-2/>
      <city>LARGO</city>
      <state>FL</state>
      <postal-code>33774</postal-code>
      <ad-content> Content</ad-content>
    </ad-type>
  </pub-code>
 </item>
```

I'm sure this is a simple syntax thing, but I can't manage to find documentation on it anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `$home->{'pub-code'}->{'ad-type'}` is the correct syntax and you need to elaborate on how it "didn't work".

Comment: huh... alright. Once I changed it back to : .$home->{'pub-code'}->{'ad-type'}->{'account-name'}. I got 'syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING'. Sorry if I didn't put enough detail into my initial question

Comment: Your XML is not valid `<image><image/>`. How do you load it?

Comment: Images come in after one more round of post-processing matching against a set of id's. I backed up the number of tags I was trying to access and got it working so maybe it was tripping when it got deep enough to see that <image></image> issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [basic usage section for SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php):

> Accessing elements within an XML document that contain characters not
>   permitted under PHP's naming convention (e.g. the hyphen) can be
>   accomplished by encapsulating the element name within braces and the
>   apostrophe.
>
> Example #3 Getting `<line>`
>
> ```
> <?php include 'example.php';
>
> $movies = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
>
> echo $movies->movie->{'great-lines'}->line; ?>
> ```

This relies on PHP's ["variable variables"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) functionality.

Comment: I'm using simplexml_load_string instead of SimpleXMLElement to create  $topRSS and getting: error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING. Could that be the root issue?

Comment: `simplexml_load_string()` returns a SimpleXMLElement, so it'll be equivalent to the code in my answer. I'd check to make sure you're using the correct form of quotes--they sometimes get replaced with ticks or other marks, especially when copy-pasted.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I got rid of all of the extraneous code and replaced the quotes and it worked - at least for a single hyphenated field.